# Facebook market page discrepancy between fan and people reach

Tags: facebook, social-media

Here is my issue: I'm managed on market Page targeted on the UK. Looking at my "People" performance (From Facebook Insight dashboard) I have the following:

```
91% of fan from UK
8,9% of fan from Ireland
0,34% of fan from France
etc...
```

While looking at my reach I have:

```
63% of people reached in the UK
24% of people reached in the US
12% of people reached in MX(mexico)
```

So why does my fan doesn't match my reach. And why I'm reaching Mexico while I don't have any specific connection with this country?

Comment: Why would it match?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!

I think that you are comparing two type of data that do not need to be related:

The first one (people performance) is regarding people who are your fans. People who are following you and may or not being interacting with your posts.

The second one is more about the reach. It may be different because some of your content has been shared by people who have friends in Mexico or the US. And then that content has been well accepted in those countries (people have share it there too). What is clear here is that the content you are sharing is being appealing for people in The US and Mexico.

Hope it helps.